# Create search page in Atom or RSS format from Elasticsearch index that returns results in JSON

Tags: json, xml, elasticsearch, salesforce

I have an Elasticsearch index of different documents (title, URL, text). I am trying to use the SalesForce federated search feature. [Their documentation states](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.federated_search.meta/federated_search/federated_search_intro.htm): The external search provider returns results in Atom or RSS format encoded in UTF-8, as defined by the OpenSearch and Atom and RSS specifications.

Elasticsearch only returns results in JSON.

Is there anyway to build a search page that can query the ES index, get results in JSON, parse the results, and return that in Atom or RSS? And would that potentially solve my issue? (The main issue is that Elasticsearch cannot return results in an XML format.)

I don't know if what I am trying to do is even possible, and I don't know how to start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the [clients](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/index.html) that elasticsearch provides for integration with its API to build a tool that queries elasticsearch and output the result in the desired format.